# Is there a function to get the max integer (resp. number) in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a function to get the max integer (resp. min) in oracle?
I know that I can find the value ([there for instance](https://www.mat.unical.it/%7Erullo/teaching/basidati_ev/aa09-10/materialedidatticolab/Oracle%20Datatypes.pdf) ), but I would prefer to avoid writing this. (less code, less typing mistakes ...)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a constant for it in the standard or dbms_standard packages. The maximum supported by the number data type might be too high to be really useful anyway. If you need a maximum that's relevant to your application you could define it in your own package as a constant.

Comment: Hi - Why would you need to know the max value a datatype can hold when writing code?

Comment: @NickW I have a function that say if somethings is in a interval. There is a case where  the interval is infinite. I don't really need to use the max /min value of an integer but it enable to factorize code.

Answer (score 1):

This does not particularly make sense as it is dependant on the scale and precision of the `NUMBER` column.

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  value1 NUMBER,
  value2 NUMBER(*,0),
  value3 NUMBER(38),
  value4 NUMBER(10,0),
  value5 NUMBER(10,5),
  value6 NUMBER(10,-2)
);
```

Then you can insert:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (
  value1,
  value2,
  value3,
  value4,
  value5,
  value6
) VALUES (
  9.9999999999999999999999999999999999999e125,
  99999999999999999999999999999999999999,
  99999999999999999999999999999999999999,
  9999999999,
  99999.99999,
  999999999900
);
```

They are all `NUMBER` columns but they have different maximum values.

---

If you want to store a maximum for a particular column (or preferably, for a set of units) somewhere then write your own package:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE constants IS
  SUBTYPE DECIBEL IS NUMBER(6,4);
  SUBTYPE NEWTON  IS NUMBER(12,2);

  MAX_DECIBELS CONSTANT DECIBEL := 99.9999;
  MAX_NEWTONS  CONSTANT NEWTON  := 9999999999.99;
  
  FUNCTION get_max_decibels RETURN DECIBEL;
  FUNCTION get_max_newtons  RETURN NEWTON;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY constants IS
  FUNCTION get_max_decibels RETURN DECIBEL
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN MAX_DECIBELS;
  END;

  FUNCTION get_max_newtons  RETURN NEWTON
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN MAX_NEWTONS;
  END;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8d8f327ff045390aa6189456996e8095)*